# springmvc validate httpsession containing userobject

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httpsession, session-management

I need to validate HttpSession (for Spring MVC Application) in a better way for my current Project.

Here is the Scenario:

1) Once user is successfully validated, `userObject` object is added to httpSession class

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute(AppConstants.LOGGEDIN_PARAM, userDetail);
```

2) Then for each request, `userObject` is retrieved from HttpSession Class to validate user Session

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/apply", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getTourApplyPage(HttpServletRequest req, ModelMap map) {
    UserDetailTO userDetail = (UserDetailTO) req.getSession().getAttribute(AppConstants.LOGGEDIN_PARAM);
    Long employeeId = userDetail.getUserType() == 1 ? userDetail.getEmployeeId():userDetail.getUserId();
    if (employeeId == 0) {
        req.setAttribute(AppConstants.MSG_PARAM, "Invalid employee Id.");
        return userDetail.getUserType() == 1 ? AppConstants.PIS_MESSAGE : AppConstants.ADMIN_PIS_MESSAGE;
     }
     ...
}
```

There can be better approaches to set `userDetail` object inside `HttpSession` but I had a restriction to not change this implementation (Point 1).

Can it possible to change getting a better implementation for getting a `userDetail` object from `HttpSession` (Point 2)?

Comment: You want to add and retrieve from session object for validation...?

Comment: @Hema I don't want to change addition to session object since its common for whole application. But I want to change `retrieve from session object for validation` . So that i can avoid the code repetition (for let say 5 methods) for user session validation inside my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to write a better implementation for getting a `userDetail` object from `httpSession`?

Working at such a high level of abstraction, as controllers are at, you don't necessarily need to inject neither an `HttpServletRequest` nor an `HttpSession`.

You can make your controller session-scoped and inject a session-scoped bean there. The bean can hold a `userDetails` and a message for failed validations.

```
@RestController
@Scope("session")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private SessionDetails details;

    @PostMapping(path = "/validate")
    public void validate() {
        details.setUserDetails(...);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/apply")
    public String apply() {
        final UserDetailTO userDetails = details.getUserDetails();
        ...
    }

}

@Component
@Scope("session")
class SessionDetails {
    private String message;
    private UserDetailTO userDetails;
    // getters & setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regrets for late reply. I had few doubts 1) how to access message on the jsp i had set for invalid session in the controller ? 2) what is the use of of `ProxyMode` attribute in `Scope` annotation ?

Comment: @Ankit 1) I have not worked with JSP enough to answer 2) it determines how the proxy will be created (interface-based or subclass-based approach to choose)